# React - Conditional Rendering with Switch and boolean case

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, switch-statement, boolean-expression

I would like to clarify a doubt on React Conditional Rendering with Switch Case

I have an implementation with conditions. ie I have to set a string value based on boolean case

For example

```
 let str = "";
    
    switch(some object)
    {
     case object.yes:  // The case here is boolean. IS it possible to set boolean case. I did try but the value is not set correctly based on the case in the str variable.
       str = "Yes"
    break:
    case object.no:
    str = "No"
    break;
    }
```

IF the above code is not possible, I will use if ... else. But during code review, surely I will be asked why I did not use Switch instead of if ...else. I want to give a convincing answer. I did seach tutorials but I can only find string case and not boolean case for React.

Just want to verify if boolean case is possible.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution is to use an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

```js
const object = {
    yes: true,
    no: false
}

const str = (() => {
    switch (true) {
        case object.yes: // The case here is boolean. IS it possible to set boolean case. I did try but the value is not set correctly based on the case in the str variable.
            return "Yes";
        case object.no:
            return "No";
        default:
            return "Unknown";
    }
})();

console.log(str);
```